# Is it possible to undelete a question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Is there a way to undelete a question? I deleted it, and now when I try to re-post it, I cannot as the system recognizes it as a duplicate question.

Comment: Which question? I don't see any deleted questions for your account.

Comment: @mbq: I had probably undeleted it already by the time you saw this.

Answer (score 6):

Ask a moderator ;-) I undeleted your question for you.

I don't believe you can do so yourself, though, because the system doesn't let you see deleted questions. If you could see them, I *think* you would be able to undelete them. (Something to look forward to when you get 10k rep perhaps?)

Comment: I'm quite sure I can see my deleted questions (2 test questions.)